# Why does RMarkdown not properly escape the second LaTeX table?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I develop the R package **vtable** and someone recently reported this bug that I find very confusing regarding RMarkdown.

Specifically, when knitting to PDF, the first table I output is fine, but the second one isn't properly escaped. *But only on its first line*.

Here's an example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "Date"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(vtable)
d <- data.frame(a = 1)
```

```{r b1, results = 'asis'}
vtable(d, out = 'latex')
```

```{r b2, results = 'asis'}
vtable(d, out = 'latex')
```
````

Note that if I leave out the `b2` chunk, this builds to PDF fine. But with it in, the build fails because only the *first* table comes out fine. In the `.tex` output the code for it is

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
 \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1} 

\caption{Variable Table}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.290909090909091\textwidth}p{0.145454545454545\textwidth}p{0.363636363636364\textwidth}}
\hline
\hline
Name & Class & Values \\ 
\hline
a & numeric & Num: 1 to 1\\ 
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But the *second* one is messed up, with some of the characters being improperly escaped and treated as text. Even weirder, *only the first line* is messed up. The LaTeX code for this table is the exact same as the previous code chunk, except that the first line is

```
\textbackslash begin\{table\}{[}!htbp{]} \centering
```

The rest works fine. If I add a third/fourth/etc. table they similarly have a messed up first line.

So what in RMarkdown is causing only the *first line* of the *second and subsequent tables* to be improperly escaped? And, any idea on how I can make the tables show up properly? Thank you!

Comment: Your code works in sweave but it looks like something in markdown doesn't like all the newlines you have added (latex often doesn't like theses as well). It is enough to change line 77 of `dftoLaTeX`  (`table.latex <- "\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering \n \\renewcommand*{\\arraystretch}{1.1} \n"`) to `table.latex <- "\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering \\renewcommand*{\\arraystretch}{1.1} \n"` . (I would also work to remove all the line spaces that are added around your latex code, captions etc)

Comment: Fantastic! I will try this out, thank you.

Comment: This did work by the way, thanks again. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Good stuff. Pease feel free to self answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from the comment by @user20650 above:

The output from `vtable()` (via `dftoHTML()`), before escaping, starts

```
"\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering \n \\renewcommand*{\\arraystretch}{1.1} \n"
```

And RMarkdown has a hard time with all those newlines `\n`

By changing the before-escape output to instead be

```
"\\begin{table}[!htbp] \\centering \\renewcommand*{\\arraystretch}{1.1}"
```

the problem is solved.